# Facebook acheivment registeration error

Tags: facebook

i try to register an achievement for my game app thorough Graph API Explorer using a POST to https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/achievements with access_token =xxxxxx ,achievement = right url and display_order =1 but it throws the following error

{
"error": {
"message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 15
}
}

. i have checked the achievment url and my app access token in the object debugger and it gives right result. But still im getting the above when try to register my achievement. i have checked evrywhere i could to find a solution but didnt get any (although there where similar post which didnt a give solution). Any help will be much much appreciated as it really takes my lot of time figuring out a solution

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's the app access token retrieved from the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/ and not the user's access token?

If you're doing this with the Graph API Explorer instead of in code or manually, you need to replace the access token the Graph API explorer is using with the one you retrieved via those instructions